# Transform one XML file to another XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

### Question: How can I Transform one XML file format to another XML file format using XSLT. I am new to xml/xslt so I need help.I need to spit a string inside the xml.

XML1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root type="array">
<persons>
<person_id>_:genid1</person_id>
<type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
<oneofs>
<oneof>This is a very long string</oneof>
</oneofs>
</persons>
<persons>
<person_id>_:genid108</person_id>
<type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
<oneofs>
<oneof>This is  another very long string</oneof>
</oneofs>
</persons>
</root>
```

XML2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root type="array">
<persons>
<person_id>_:genid1</person_id>
<type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
<oneofs>
<oneof>This is </oneof>
<oneofagain>a very long string</oneofagain>
</oneofs>
</persons>
<persons>
<person_id>_:genid108</person_id>
<type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
<oneofs>
<oneof>This is </oneof>
<oneofagain>another very long string</oneofagain>
</oneofs>
</persons>
</root>
```

Comment: What version of XSLT? If 2.0+, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742209/splitting-of-strings-based-on-the-required-length

Comment: Please post a [mcve] and show your attempt.

Comment: The version is 1.0

Comment: In that case, I'd start with an identity transform and add a named template that you can pass the string being split, the length, and the name of the element to wrap the substring in. It should be a recursive template so it should call itself when needed. You can match `oneof` and initially call the named template from there. Try that then come back with any issues.

Comment: How do I do that? I am very new to xslt? Please help?

Comment: You've asked three question here, and every one has been too broad.  This site is not for code-on-demand requests.  Please read [ask] before posting another too broad question.  If you don't include an attempt, you'll (rarely) get good help.  If you do show effort, you'll get outstanding help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very broad question, but maybe this will help...

**XML Input**

```
<root type="array">
    <persons>
        <person_id>_:genid1</person_id>
        <type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
        <oneofs>
            <oneof>This is a very long string</oneof>
        </oneofs>
    </persons>
    <persons>
        <person_id>_:genid108</person_id>
        <type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
        <oneofs>
            <oneof>This is  another very long string</oneof>
        </oneofs>
    </persons>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Identity template-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oneof">
    <xsl:call-template name="split">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="name" select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="length" select="10"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring($input, $length + 1)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($input, 1, $length)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="$remaining">
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remaining"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<root type="array">
   <persons>
      <person_id>_:genid1</person_id>
      <type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
      <oneofs>
         <oneof>This is a </oneof>
         <oneof>very long </oneof>
         <oneof>string</oneof>
      </oneofs>
   </persons>
   <persons>
      <person_id>_:genid108</person_id>
      <type>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Datatype</type>
      <oneofs>
         <oneof>This is  a</oneof>
         <oneof>nother ver</oneof>
         <oneof>y long str</oneof>
         <oneof>ing</oneof>
      </oneofs>
   </persons>
</root>
```

Take a look at the above and let me know what doesn't make sense.

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHV

Comment: It will be interesting to see if user9566024 appreciates this generous answer or goes full help vampire on Daniel Haley.  :-)

Comment: Almost there and  I really need the second <oneof> to be <oneofagain>and the third to be <oneofagainagain>. Need to able to change the names please.

Comment: *facepalm* did you try to figure it out yourself? Hint: you could add “again” to the “name” with-param. Super easy!

Comment: ***Called it.***

Comment: @kjhughes - yeah you did!

Comment: I tried      <xsl:with-param name="name" + "again"   select="$name"/>

Comment: error  : a name was started with an invalid character.

Comment: @user9566024 - In XSLT/XPath, you can concatenate strings by using `concat()`. Like `<xsl:with-param name="name" select="concat($name,'again')"/>`. See the updated fiddle here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiHV/1

Comment: Got It. Excellent. Sir!